# 2nd pass builds get slower and slower with Webpack 2

Tags: webpack-hmr, webpack-2

I'm trying out webpack 2 with HMR and I encountered a strange problem. 
After each modification, incremental update is finished very quickly and then the message `Compilation needs an additional pass and will compile again.` is displayed. After that it takes a few seconds for the build to finish.

The problem is that after each change, the build (the second pass) lasts approximately half a second longer and becomes unusable after a while.

I'm using webpack 2.1.0 beta 4 with style, css, sass and babel loaders.

I would appreciate any idea on how to make build times constant.

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2211. Some people solved it by removing the `--hot` flag.